# "[warning] Invalid argument supplied for foreach() Migration.php:641"

Tags: 8, migrations

Why does this error appear when I use the `drush ms` command?

> [warning] Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()` Migration.php:641

Answer (score 0):

Usually this comes from having incorrectly coded a hard value in your migration yml script. As noted in the following example:

```
process:
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 'profile'
  status: 1
  uid:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_value
      source: user_id
      method: row
      value: 1
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      no_stub: true
      migration: tabs_users
      source: user_id

  is_default: '1'
  created: created
  changed: user_lastvisit
```

Here I show a few different approaches, but one is wrong. Specifically, the `status:` line is trying to set a value of **1** but the migrate module is assuming it is a variable and since it is not set previously in the **source** section of the yml script, drupal is barfing. To fix this, do what is done in either the **type** line OR the **is_default** line; explicitly set the value via the **default_value** plugin OR **encapsulate your value in quotes**. This is identified in the documentation but can be easily overlooked when quickly coding up a solution.